# How to send form data with the string combine both by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here, I have a file selector in my html and the file selected by it will send to go API using `formData` send by ajax. But now I have to send a simple string with `data` in ajax I'm appending with the `formData` variable but in console there is no data of string.

The code I'm using is:-

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="imageSelector"><br><br>

const data = new FormData();
var inputFile = $('#imageSelector').val().split('\\').pop();
data.append("file", $("#imageSelector")[0].files[0], inputFile);
data.append("category", "Eatables");
console.log(data)
$.ajax({
      url: "/api/v1/upload",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: data,
      success: function(response){ 
          console.log(response)
      }
 });
```

How I will send the form data with the string with the data variable that golang api will receive data?

Comment: Can you use the querystring if it's suitable?

Comment: @PhilCooper no I'm integrating it with the golang api's. If I use query string then it will effect on api's

Answer (score 0):

you can not direct console.log(data),you can check like this `console.log(data.get('category'))`

Answer (score 0):

you have to do a simple thing convert it into json like I told you below.

```
data.append("category", JSON.stringify(category))
```

On golang while receiving you have to use `c.PostForm("category")` (if you are using gin package) and It will show the output into double quoted string if you want to remove them also the you will use below code:-

```
data.append("category", JSON.stringify(category).replace(/\"/g, ""));
```

I hope it will help you:)